# Visual Studio 2019でデバッグコンソールが文字化けする

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

Windows10上のVisual Studio 2019 でwin32 APIを使ったプロジェクトをデバッグモードで実行するとデバッグコンソールの表示が文字化けします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

デバッグコンソールのプロパティを見てみるとコードページが **65001(UTF-8)** となっていたためコンパイルオプションに`/execution-charset:utf-8`を追加してみましたが文字化けは治りませんでした。
(`/execution-charset:utf-8`は実行時の文字コードをutf-8にする)

[/文字セット (実行文字セットの設定) | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/build/reference/execution-charset-set-execution-character-set?view=msvc-160)

どうすればいいのでしょうか?

---

#### 追記

Windowsの設定をいろいろ見直していたところ、`ワールドワイド言語サポートでUnicode UTF-8を使用`という項目が有効になっていました。
これを解除して再起動したところ、解決しました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

(おそらくデバッガの文字コードがShift-JISになっており、それをUTF-8の文字コードを扱うようになっていたデバッグコンソールに出力したため文字化けしたのだと思います)

とりあえず解決したのですが、
この項目を有効にしたままデバッグコンソールを使う方法はないのでしょうか?
(どこかでデバッガの出力のエンコーディングを変えることはできないのでしょうか?)

Comment: デバッグ環境のためにプログラムの設定を変えるのは本末転倒です。まずプログラムとしてどうありたいか、それを踏まえてデバッグ環境としてどうありたいか、を示してください。

Comment: この記事が参考になるかも。[C++ Visual Studio character encoding issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1857668/9014308) あと直接は関係無いかもですが。[Visual Studio で UTF-8 でC++を書いたら心が折れそうになった件](http://tech.hikware.com/article/20171020a.html), [［C++］コンソール出力にchar8_t文字列を出力したい！](https://onihusube.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/04/03/211442)

Comment: 公開しても問題無い程度のサンプルプロジェクトを作って、プロジェクト全体を何処かに上げておけば、色んな人が色々試せるのでは？ WindowsやVisualStudio本体側の設定とかも関係するかもしれませんが。

Comment: 一応解決したのですが、UTF-8のままでデバッガの出力を見れる方法はないのでしょうか?

Comment: 古いのでVS2019には当てはまらないかもですが、もしかしたらこの記事で何か変わるかも。[Visual Studio のデバッガで文字列を UTF-8 で表示させる](https://qiita.com/takeda25/items/6a5a559e33011031e1a0) 他にはこんな議論も。[文字化けについて](https://dixq.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=20799)

Comment: どうにもわからないようでしたら、Visual Studio IDE画面右上隅の「フィードバックの送信」を使って同様の記事を探して、無ければ質問/要望を出してみてはどうでしょう？